# Is $1600 enough to live in Romania for a non-Romanian?

Tags: romanian-citizens

I’m from Lebanon and I’ve received a job offer and Visa of work from my relatives in Romania to work in a company with 1600$ per month,

So is it enough to live and save money ?

Later when I get the residence, I’m planning to invite my husband to follow me and live together in Romania, so I’m analyzing the situation now,
Is it worth to take this step (moving together), also my husband is working in IT field, is it easy to find a job for him? and what’s our chances to live a good life in Romania?

Thank you so much.

Comment: If your relatives in Romania are offering you a job, can’t you discuss this topic with them?

Comment: Everybody has a different notion of what "enough" is. You need to compare that to your current standards of living. A lot of people live with a lot less, some wouldn't even consider such an offer.

Comment: The average salary in Romania is currently about RON 2600 or USD 620, so it is obviously possible to live with much less money than USD 1600 per month. The cost of living in Romania vary extremely between different regions and it is not easy for us to guess what living standards you are aiming at.